# Javascript countdown timer + PHP code inside JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer, countdown

I need help with countdown timer in javascript.I found the code below in PHPJabbers. This code works fine, but when I reload the page the time goes back to its initial time. I want to retain the time even if I load the page. I want also to add PHP function inside if seconds == 0. I'm not sure if it's possible. Thanks in advance

```
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
<script>
var seconds = 60;
    function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +    remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
    } else {    
        seconds--;
    }
    }
var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Use `cookies` or HTML5 `localStorage`

Comment: Thank you for the reply @hindmost. But which of the two is better?

Comment: It's better to use both of them

Comment: How about the PHP function inside the if(seconds == 0) {}. I tried to put my PHP code inside it, but It's not working.

Comment: You can't call PHP function inside JS directly. You only can use indirect call through AJAX.

Comment: @hindmost I don't know how to do it in AJAX. I tried to get the value of the span tag, but I still have to click button to get the time.

Comment: @rrr, In your code above where should we navigate to other window based on the time elapse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this, (implemented using cookies)

```
                function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
                {
                var d = new Date();
                d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
                document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
                }
                function getCookie(cname)
                {
                var name = cname + "=";
                var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++)
                  {
                  var c = ca[i].trim();
                  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
                  }
                return "";
                }

                //check existing cookie
                cook=getCookie("my_cookie");

                if(cook==""){
                   //cookie not found, so set seconds=60
                   var seconds = 60;
                }else{
                     seconds = cook;
                     console.log(cook);
                }

                function secondPassed() {
                    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
                    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
                    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
                        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
                    }
                    //store seconds to cookie
                    setCookie("my_cookie",seconds,5); //here 5 is expiry days

                    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +    remainingSeconds;
                    if (seconds == 0) {
                        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
                        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
                    } else {    
                        seconds--;
                    }
                }

                var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FnsY4/)

Comment: @Bhavesh Nice code, but is it possible to modify it to work so that the countdown is still running if someone navigates away from the specific page that has the timer, and then returns to it later?

Answer (score 0):

Nice solution by bhavesh.. If someone wants to show the days,hour,mins, seconds together then they can refer this code.

```
Reverse timer from javascript:

var target_date = new Date('Aug 01 2014 20:47:00').getTime();
    var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
    var countdown = document.getElementById('timeremaining');
    var countdownTimer = setInterval(function () {
        var current_date = new Date().getTime();
        var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

        days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
        seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

        hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
        seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
        minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
        seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

        if(days <= 0 && hours <= 0 && minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0 )
        {
           document.getElementById('timeremaining').innerHTML = '';
           clearInterval(countdownTimer);              
        }
        else
        {       
            if(days>0)
              {
                 days= days+'d,';
              } 
              else
              {
                 days='';
              }            
            countdown.innerHTML ='( ' + days + checkTime(hours) + ':'+ checkTime(minutes) + ':' + checkTime(seconds) +' remaining)';    
        }
    }, 1000);

    function checkTime(i) {
        if (i < 10) {i = '0' + i};  
        return i;
    }
```

Comment: Bottom link is dead :( Do you still have the jsfiddle link somewhere?